# What could be done to improve this header?

Tags: javascript, header

I would like to know:

- is this header of professional quality?
- if not, what could I add or change?

I've tried not absolutely positioning the elements in the header and floating the button to the right, but it always results in the button being too low. Should I just keep the elements absolutely positioned, or is there another method I don't know about?

I am also having trouble setting proper ids and classes for my elements, do you know of a way to make this code more DRY?

I am aware that this is far from professional quality and that I'm an idiot, but I'm having trouble writing clean code and I don't know which way is best to make a header like this. I've tried googling help, and looking at code from other websites, but I'm always perplexed by their examples.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me some pointers, thanks!

HTML:

```
<header id="master-head">
    <div id="master-head-content">

        <span id="master-head-title">Brodie Been</span>

        <span id="master-head-primary">
            <a href="#">My Work</a>
            <a href="#">About Me</a>
        </span>

        <span id="master-head-secondary" class="menu-right">
            <button id="master-head-contact">CONTACT ME</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
$shadowColor:rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
$softBlack:#404040;
$primaryColor:#348DC8;

@mixin vertCenter{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(0, -50%);
}


body{
    background:#404040;
    font-family:Open Sans;

    button{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        border:none;
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size:14px;
        background:$primaryColor;

        &:hover{
            cursor:pointer;
            color:white;
            background:$softBlack;
        }
    }
}








#master-head{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    font-size:14px;
    background:white;

    #master-head-content{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        #master-head-title{
            @include vertCenter;
            padding-left:50px;
            font-size:24px;
        }

        #master-head-primary{
            @include vertCenter;
            padding-left:300px;

            a{
                text-decoration:none;
                color:inherit;
                margin-right:30px;

                &:hover{
                    margin-bottom:-1px;
                    border-bottom:1px solid black;
                }
            }
        }

        #master-head-secondary{
            @include vertCenter;
            right:50px;

            #master-head-contact{
                width:130px;
                height:50px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better suited for codereview than SO

Comment: I think its pretty fine, what i would do tho is make it a little bit more SEO friendly by using the appropriate text tags for example: <title> for the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack overflow probably isn't the place for this for future reference but don't sweat it! Here's my take:

1. Never use ids with css. [(Here is an explanation why)](https://dev.to/claireparker/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4)
2. You should avoid nesting element selectors in css. Instead I recommend following [BEM](http://getbem.com/naming/).
3. When naming my variables I like to format them based on type. So call your colors $color-black instead of just $black etc.
4. I would not use named css colors. Either use variables or write them out. Even with "safe" colors like black and white it just looks sloppy.
5. This goes back to #2 but avoid using element types as selectors. Give your button etc classes and use them instead. Unless of course that button style is going to be universal within your site.

Hopefully this feedback helps you! Good luck with your header.